# Broadcast receiver onReceive() never called - Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I've been testing sending and receiving broadcasts in my application but I have a problem. The service starts and I get the Toast to say the broadcast has been sent but onReceive is never called in the myMapView class. I've only included the code I think is relevant below... any help would be much appreciated. I don't think I'm registering the receiver correctly.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class myLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private static final String GEO_LNG = "GEO_LNG";
    private static final String GEO_LAT = "GEO_LAT";

    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location){


    if (location != null){

            Double geoLat = location.getLatitude() * 1E6;
            Double geoLng = location.getLongitude() * 1E6;

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, myMapView.class);
            intent.putExtra(GEO_LNG,geoLng);
            intent.putExtra(GEO_LAT, geoLat);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            Toast.makeText(myLocationService.this, "Broadcast sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }   
    else{
        Toast.makeText(myLocationService.this, "Location = null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
}


public class myMapView extends MapActivity{
    private static final String GEO_LNG = "GEO_LNG";
    private static final String GEO_LAT = "GEO_LAT";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);     

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(GEO_LONG);
    filter.addAction(GEO_LAT);
    registerReceiver(locationRec, filter);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, myLocationService.class);

            startService(i);
}

    private BroadcastReceiver locationRec = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                       double geoLng = intent.getExtras().getDouble(GEO_LONG);
                       double geoLat = intent.getExtras().getDouble(GEO_LAT);
            Toast.makeText(GeoTrailsMap.this, "Got broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    };
```

**Edit** I've modified my code to look like this, but I'm still not having any luck with receiving the broadcasts.

```
public class myLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {
private static final String GEO_LNG = "GEO_LNG";
private static final String GEO_LAT = "GEO_LAT";
public static final String LOCATION_UPDATE = "LOCATION_UPDATE";

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location){


if (location != null){

        Double geoLat = location.getLatitude() * 1E6;
        Double geoLng = location.getLongitude() * 1E6;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, myMapView.class);
        intent.putExtra(GEO_LNG,geoLng);
        intent.putExtra(GEO_LAT, geoLat);
        intent.setAction(LOCATION_UPDATE);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        Toast.makeText(myLocationService.this, "Broadcast sent",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
    else{
    Toast.makeText(myLocationService.this, "Location = null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
}


public class myMapView extends MapActivity{
private static final String GEO_LNG = "GEO_LNG";
private static final String GEO_LAT = "GEO_LAT";
private static final String LOCATION_UPDATE = myLocationService.LOCATION_UPDATE;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);     

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(LOCATION_UPDATE);
    registerReceiver(locationRec, filter);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, myLocationService.class);

    startService(i);
}

private BroadcastReceiver locationRec = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                   double geoLng = intent.getExtras().getDouble(GEO_LNG);
                   double geoLat = intent.getExtras().getDouble(GEO_LAT);
        Toast.makeText(GeoTrailsMap.this, "Got broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intent that's firing doesn't have an action set.  When you call "addAction" in the IntentFilter here:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(GEO_LNG);
    filter.addAction(GEO_LAT);
    registerReceiver(locationRec, filter);
```

You're adding actions that the receiver will listen for (in this case, the receiver will listen for GEO_LNG and GEO_LAT.

In the service where you fire the intent, the intent needs to contain that action in order for the receiver to spot it.  Decide which one you want to send, and then modify the Intent-firing code to look like this:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, myMapView.class);
        // Here you're using GEO_LNG as both the Intent action, and a label 
        // for data being passed over.  Might want to change that for clarity?
        intent.putExtra(GEO_LNG, geoLng);
        intent.putExtra(GEO_LAT, geoLat);
        intent.setAction(GEO_LNG);
        ...
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this! I think I'm almost there, please could you take a look at my edit and see what you think? Still not getting the broadcasts..

Comment: Hi I got it working. I changed this line Intent intent = new Intent(this, myMapView.class); to.. Intent intent = new Intent(); and it worked

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml should include:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Instead of using broadcast receiver try:

```
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private GeoUpdateHandler geoUpdateHandler;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            geoUpdateHandler = new GeoUpdateHandler();
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                    0, geoUpdateHandler);
}

public void onStop()
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(geoUpdateHandler);
        super.onStop();

    }

public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

        private boolean _bLocationChangeReceived = false;

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
            int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
            if(!_bLocationChangeReceived)
            {
            mapController.animateTo(point); //  mapController.setCenter(point);
            _bLocationChangeReceived = true;
            }
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Testing", "My location!");
            itemizedoverlay.resetOverlay(overlayitem, 0);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
```